# Run each Python script in directory individually

Tags: python, command-line, structure, project

My Python project contains a single directory full of different scripts which each perform different functions. Each script uses methods from other scripts by including them, so at the top of each script it will have:

```
from first import *
from second import *
from fourth import *
```

I can only assume that the program will compile and run these scripts upon importing them because any code outside of a method in the imported classes is run before anything else. This is not what I want.
What I am trying to do is run each script from the command line. Each script has code outside of any function which perform's it's unique function, for example:

```
python first.py
```

will run all contents of first.py outside any methods sequentially. It will perform it's own unique function, calling methods from second.py for example, but not executing the unique function of second.py.

I'm not sure if this is clear enough and I'm not sure if somebody could suggest a solution for this, or maybe an alternative way of doing this.

Comment: you shouldn't `import *`. explicitly import the functions/classes you need from the other files rather than importing everything. you can (and likely should) include an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block in your script to get code to only run when you call from the command line

Comment: so You want to be able to run only the things that were originally in the file? ok so if You want to stop the execution of script because it gets imported You should use `if __name__ == "main":` block as mentioned in the above comment and put there all of the function calls and so on that You don't want executed by import